# How to schedule a scrapy command

Tags: cmd, scrapy, schedule

So I've been using scrapy for web-scraping. I've developed the script and was wondering if there is anyway I can use the Task Scheduler in Windows to get it to run my scrapy command to scrape various sites with the Command Prompt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you have to provide mode details on the windows. Is it XP, Win7, Win8

In general there is a scheduler in windows and yes you can schedule any command. 
Here is how you do it with win7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7